# Legend, title and axis labels compressed in Gnuplot output

Tags: gnuplot

I am making a graph in gnuplot and it seems when I select an output to be *pdf* all of the labels get compressed together (there are no spaces between letters in a word)

Here is my code:

```
set term pdf
set out "spiral_r.pdf"

set log xy
set key left

set title "Distance to the center" font ",14"
set xlabel "i^{1/2}" font ",10"
set ylabel "Disctance" font ",10"

plot 'spiral.dat' u (sqrt($1)):(sqrt($2*$2+$3*$3)) w l title "Distance"

quit
```

And here is the output [image: output]
 that I am getting. The part I don't understand is if I change the output to *png* the **same** code works fine, but I need the output to be in *pdf*.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a bad pango/cairo library version.  If you upgrade or downgrade the libraries to a working version then gnuplot will magically work also.

Detailed version information will vary with your operating system. One previously reported analysis is that on MacOS pango 1.43 is good but 1.44 is bad.  If you recently upgraded a Mac you may have ended up with a bad library.

```
https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/2194/
```

Comment: What is pango/cairo library? And how do I uprgade it?